# How to get ALL Twitter followers with MGTwitterEngine's getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus?

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I don't see the support of paging through or some kind of way to set cursor to get to the next result.

Comment: sorry .. I want to say that .. have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check discussion here.. http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/9d14524e9a8b6671/901f6d59a0c21e95#901f6d59a0c21e95

I think it may help us.

Comment: Yup, that's 1 solution but it's not 1 function call. Thanks for the resource, maybe this is the best solution for now.

Comment: yes i think .. but till i have not implement it.. Seymour if it works for you then please accept answer